# INSERT with INNER JOIN and Predetermined Values

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I'm trying to add 9500 or so records to a table from a different table, the problem is that the table I'm adding them to has an egregious amount of colums while the table I'm pulling from is pretty normalized so I'm not quite sure how to do the inner join on it, this is what I have so far:

```
INSERT INTO Products (Code, ManufacturerId, VendorId, IsActive, Name, NamePlural, ShortDescription, Description, UpSellMessage, Cost, Price, IsOnSale, SalePrice, IsShipable, ShipPrice, Weight, Length, Width, Height, HasCountryTax, HasStateTax, HasLocalTax, DateAdded, Keywords, Inventory_Tracked, DropShip, DownloadOneTime, DealTimeIsActive, MMIsActive, ProductType, RecurringSubscriptionPrice, PaymentPeriod, Term, BillingDelay, SaleType, BundleGroupID, ComputePrice, PriceUp, PriceChangedAmount, PriceChangedType, SwatchesPerRow, ChangeOnClick, ChangeOnMouseover, ShowCloseUpLink, LinkBigImage, SwatchAllignment, DescriptionAllignment, DetailLink)
FROM otherProducts table2
INNER JOIN table2
VALUES (table2.col1, 1, 1, 0, table2.col1, table2.col1, table2.col4, table2.col4, 'some message that does not matter', table2.col3, table2.col2, 0, '0', 1, '8', '3', '8', '8', '8', 1, 1, 1, '12/27/2013', ' ', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, '0', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, '0', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, table2.col1+'.aspx');
```

I can see this is a giant mess, and it just gives me errors, can anyone help me with this?

Comment: you are just missing the `SELECT` clause between `INSERT INTO` and `FROM`, then remove the `VALUES` clause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want the `insert . . . select` syntax:

```
INSERT INTO Products (Code, ManufacturerId, VendorId, IsActive, Name, NamePlural, ShortDescription, Description, UpSellMessage, Cost, Price, IsOnSale, SalePrice, IsShipable, ShipPrice, Weight, Length, Width, Height, HasCountryTax, HasStateTax, HasLocalTax, DateAdded, Keywords, Inventory_Tracked, DropShip, DownloadOneTime, DealTimeIsActive, MMIsActive, ProductType, RecurringSubscriptionPrice, PaymentPeriod, Term, BillingDelay, SaleType, BundleGroupID, ComputePrice, PriceUp, PriceChangedAmount, PriceChangedType, SwatchesPerRow, ChangeOnClick, ChangeOnMouseover, ShowCloseUpLink, LinkBigImage, SwatchAllignment, DescriptionAllignment, DetailLink)
    select table2.col1, 1, 1, 0, table2.col1, table2.col1, table2.col4, table2.col4, 'some message that does not matter', table2.col3, table2.col2, 0, '0', 1, '8', '3', '8', '8', '8', 1, 1, 1, '12/27/2013', ' ', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, '0', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, '0', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, table2.col1+'.aspx'
    FROM otherProducts table2;
```

I don't think you need to do a `join` at all.

Comment: Thanks Gordon! I honestly didn't know that I could do this without a JOIN!